# Objective-c Method to get a number then countdown in 1 every second

Tags: objective-c, xcode, count, duration, countdown

i need a little help i have a method which gets value such as 50, it then assigns that value to trackDuration, so NSNumber *trackDuration = 50, i want the method to every second minus 1 from the value of trackDuration and update a label, the label being called duration.

Here's what i have so far;

```
- (void) countDown {
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];

NSNumber *trackDuration = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[iTunes currentTrack] duration]];
while (trackDuration > 0) {
    trackDuration - 1;
    int inputSeconds = [trackDuration intValue];
    int hours =  inputSeconds / 3600;
    int minutes = ( inputSeconds - hours * 3600 ) / 60; 
    int seconds = inputSeconds - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60; 
    NSString *trackDurationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d:%.2d", hours, minutes, seconds];
    [duration setStringValue:trackDurationString];
    sleep(1);
}}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advanced, Sami.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will block the main thread, and you are not assigning the value trackDuration, so it will always stay 50

```
trackDuration -1;
```

Should be:

```
trackDuration--; // or trackDuration -= 1;
```

Also I would do it like this:

```
- (void)startCountDown
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerHit:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
- (void)timerHit:(NSTimer *)p_timer
{
  if( trackDuration <= 1 && [p_timer isValid] )
     [p_timer invalidate];
 // track duration is an instance variable
 trackDuration--;
 // update LABEL
}
```

iOS 2.x or higher is required for NSTimer

Comment: The iOS requirement doesn't really matter: iPhone OS 2 was the first to support third-party apps at all, and this is obviously a Mac program anyway (as evinced by the use of SBApplication).

Comment: Thanks for the help, makes more sense but i get the follwing warning and it, doesn't seem to work; NSTimer' may not respond to '+scheduledTimerWithInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:'

Comment: The first part of that method call should be: scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work, the startCountDown method is run, which runs timerHit and the label is updated once, to the value of trackDuration however it does not repeat and minus one from the value of trackDuration and update the label.

Comment: Actually it does work, just doesn't repeat, so minuses 1 once.

Comment: @Sami this is what I use inside my own application for a keepalive timer, If its not working you are doing something wrong, and @craig is correct, it should be scheduledTimerWithTimeinterval, you should take a look at NSTimer class reference, maybe it will be more clear for you

Answer (score 0):

Having this method run in a loop will make your app go unresponsive for the whole time it's running — you won't even see any UI updates. Instead, you should use an NSTimer with an interval of one second, and update the elapsed time when the timer fires.